# DBM::Deep: Problems with transactions

Tags: database, perl, transactions, dbm

I've never done transactions (in terms of programming), therefore I don't know if there is something wrong with my script or something else:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use DBM::Deep;

my $db = DBM::Deep->new( 'foo.db' );

my $trans = $db->supports( 'transactions' );
say 'Does ', $trans ? '' : 'NOT ', 'support transactions'; 

$db->{key} = 'value';
$db->begin_work;
$db->{key1} = 'value2';
$db->rollback;
$db->{key1} = 'value1';
$db->commit;
```

Output:

```
# Does support transactions
# DBM::Deep: Cannot allocate transaction ID at ./perl1.pl line 12
```

Part of comment:

```
my $db = DBM::Deep->new( file => 'my.db', num_txns => 1 );

$db->{key} = 'value';
$db->begin_work;
$db->{key1} = 'value2';
$db->rollback;
$db->begin_work;
$db->{key1} = 'value1';
$db->commit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about taking so long to answer this question - I only just found it a few days ago. (I'm the maintainer of DBM::Deep.)

The issue is that `num_txns` is only set when the file is created. (This is because of how the DBM file is laid out on disk.) Once you've created a DBM file, then the `num_txns` value is read from the file and ignored in the call to `new()`. So, once you changed your invocation to specify `num_txns`, it wouldn't help unless you also used a new DBM file.

While I cannot change this behavior without significantly changing how the DBM file structure works (which may be a good idea, but is a huge thing to do), you should have been warned and there should have been better documentation. I have opened https://github.com/robkinyon/dbm-deep/issues/12 to track this problem and the fix(es) for it.

Comment: Also I had to set `num_txns` to 2 (or higher) - 1 for the HEAD + 1 for the transaction (as stated in the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/DBM-Deep-2.0004/lib/DBM/Deep.pod#TRANSACTIONS) the `rollback` command ends the transaction.

> rollback() This discards the changes
>   done within the transaction to the
>   mainline and ends the transaction.

Therefore you need to start a new transaction after a rollback.

```
$db->{key} = 'value';
$db->begin_work;
$db->{key1} = 'value2';
$db->rollback;
$db->begin_work;
$db->{key1} = 'value1';
$db->commit;
```

or you could do something like

```
sub my_rollback {
  my $db = shift;
  $db->rollback();
  $db->begin_work();
}

$db->{key} = 'value';
$db->begin_work;
$db->{key1} = 'value2';
my_rollback $db;
$db->{key1} = 'value1';
$db->commit;
```

or with a little black magic, you can keep the OO style

```
sub my_rollback {
  my $db = shift;
  $db->rollback();
  $db->begin_work();
};
{
  no strict 'refs';
  *{'DBM::Deep::my_rollback'} = \&my_rollback;
}

$db->{key} = 'value';
$db->begin_work;
$db->{key1} = 'value2';
$db->my_rollback;
$db->{key1} = 'value1';
$db->commit;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but I got again the same error message.

Comment: do you have the proper permissions on foo.db? try a different file name or in a different directory

Comment: also, on the call to `new` try changing the line to `my $db = DBM::Deep->new(file => 'foo.db', num_txns => 1);` with `num_txns` set between 1 and 255

Comment: @sid_com, did this help? Are you still having problems?

Comment: Still the same error-message. I added the modified script to my answer.